# Importing Multiple Excel sheets to one SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I have three Excel files which have eighteen worksheets (with column headers) each. I need to merge them into one SQL table. I tried using the Import Wizard of SQL Server, but it imports these into multiple destination tables. My goal is to have one table with all of the data in it. I have access only to the database engine, so any help using SSIS wont help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the import wizard you can change the name of the destination table.

Comment: For this kind of task I usually create a C# Source Component which loops over all tabs in all files and pushs the data into one output...

Comment: @Wouter If I give a similar name for the destination table, I get an error saying it should be unique.

Comment: @Tyron78 I know how to do it using R.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> OPENROWSET

Sample code
    `SELECT * into dbo.target_table FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=pathtoexcel.xlsx', 'select * from [sheet1$]')`

Note : accessdatabaseengine has to be installed in the sql server installed VM or physical machine